# for loop skipping intervals javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Good day!
I am trying to make a for loop but the problem is it would skip on every other number. I don't have the slightest idea on what caused it. Instead of giving 1,2,3 and so on, it would give me 1,3,4 etc. How can I possibly stop it from skipping an interval? Here is the visual result ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktx94.jpg )

```
var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("col");   
var seatNum = 0;

for (var i = cols.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    for (var j = 0; j < cols[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
      cols[i].childNodes[j].innerHTML = seatNum;
      seatNum++;
    }
  } else {
    for (var j = cols[i].childNodes.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      cols[i].childNodes[j].innerHTML = seatNum;
      seatNum++;
    }
  }
}
```

Codepen Snippet : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVbGKJ

Comment: `if(i % 2 === 0)` means if the number is even. 


I dont get what you are trying to do. Is the image the result of the error or the result you have to achieve ?

Comment: First thing I will suggest use `var j` only once as javascript does not support block scope. for second loop use `var k`. Can you also add the fiddle of your code ?

Comment: You should create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that produces the same problem. An image won't do.

Comment: @akinuri Now that SO supports code snippets, you should encourage users to use that rather than JSFiddle.

Comment: @Lauromine Thanks for the quick reply sir. The image was the result of the error.

Comment: @Michael You're right. SO's code snippet should be used when showcasing the problem. But you're not able to fiddle in the code in SO to solve the problem. If I want to try a few things, I need to copy the code to somewhere else (jsfiddle, codepen, etc.) That's why I find JSFiddle much easier to work with. I usually link/embed both of them.

Comment: if(i % 2 === 0) this part here is _it is to alternate between numbering up a column vs numbering down a column. If i is even, then number up the column... else, number down the column._ according to ForScale from Reddit

Comment: @akinuri here's the codepen link sir. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVbGKJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're modifying `childNodes` instead of `children` of `cols[i]`. They are not the same thing. Check the following image. Nodes and elements (children) are different things. The length of the `childNodes` and `children` differ. This causes the problem.

[image]

Use `children` instead of `childNodes` and it will work. There's another problem though. The numbering will start from 0. To fix that, simply start `seatNum` from 1.

```
var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
var seatNum = 1;

for (var i = cols.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    for (var j = 0; j < cols[i].children.length; j++) {
      cols[i].children[j].innerHTML = seatNum;
      seatNum++;
    }
  } else {
    for (var j = cols[i].children.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      cols[i].children[j].innerHTML = seatNum;
      seatNum++;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
var seatNum = 1;

for (var i = cols.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    for (var j = 0; j < cols[i].children.length; j++) {
      cols[i].children[j].innerHTML = seatNum;
      seatNum++;
    }
  } else {
    for (var j = cols[i].children.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      cols[i].children[j].innerHTML = seatNum;
      seatNum++;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.col,
.column {
  float: left;
}

.col div,
.column div {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

hr {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<hr> Should look like this
<div class="column">
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div>6</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayn6jsp5/)

---

Update: [JSFiddle (your original column structure)](https://jsfiddle.net/ayn6jsp5/2/)

Comment: Oh i see. Now I've learned something new today! Thank you sir!

Comment: I've tried putting this in an HTML file and it won't display the numbers. It does work on JSFiddle and Codepen tho.

Comment: Did you put the exact code into a html file, or you modified your original code and it didn't work? Copy the contents of the html in this [link(fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ayn6jsp5/1/) and put it inside a html file. It works. Also, see the update on the answer.

Answer (score 2):

the issue is that you are trying to access childnodes, which includes/counts divs as well as td in each column. As such your code executes more number of times than expected. Instead of childnodes use 'getElementByTagName()'

Answer (score 2):

use `.children` instead of `.childNodes` ... `childNodes` include #text nodes between tags, `children` do not

also, start seatNum at 1, not zero

```js
var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
var seatNum = 1;

for (var i = cols.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    for (var j = 0; j < cols[i].children.length; j++) {
      cols[i].children[j].innerHTML = seatNum;
      seatNum++;
    }
  } else {
    for (var j = cols[i].children.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      cols[i].children[j].innerHTML = seatNum;
      seatNum++;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.col,
.column {
  float: left;
}

.col div,
.column div {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

hr {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<hr>
Should look like this
<div class="column">
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div>6</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```